# Homeomorphism induced by a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$ closed as well as $A \subset U \subset X$ with $U$ open.
Consider the quotient map $q:X\rightarrow X/A$. My question is that I don't know how to prove that

$$q|_{X\smallsetminus A}:X \smallsetminus A\rightarrow (X/A) \smallsetminus (A/A)$$

and

$$q|_{U\smallsetminus A}:U \smallsetminus A\rightarrow (U/A) \smallsetminus (A/A)$$

are homeomorphisms.
Showing that they are bijective is quite trivial, but I don't really know how to prove that they are
homeomorphisms. I definitely have to use that $A$ is closed and $U$ is open as this statement is not true otherwise. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you write down the inverse functions? What do open sets of these quotient spaces look like? Also, note that since $U$ is open in $X$, it really suffices to just show that one of these maps is a homeomorphism since the exact same argument will follow for the other map.

Comment: The inverse function should be given by sending an equivalence class $[u]$ to its representative. In fact this is basicially just the identity as the equivalence relation does not do anything outside of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B\subseteq X$ is any subset then

$$q^{-1}(q(B))=\begin{cases}
B\cup A&\text{if }B\cap A\neq\emptyset \\
B&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore if $B\subseteq X\backslash A$ then $q^{-1}(q(B))=B$. Thus if additionally $B$ is open in $X$ then $q(B)$ is open in $X/A$. Next since $A$ is closed, then $B$ is open in $X\backslash A$ if and only if it is open in $X$. And therefore $q_{|X\backslash A}$ is an open map. It is of course continuous, and therefore a homeomorphism (since you've correctly noted it is a bijection).

---

As for the second question, lets first note the subtlety here. Our $U/A$ can be given two topologies: first, the subspace topology inherited from $X/A$, and second: the quotient topology from $U/A$. And normally an answer would depend on that. However we have a special situation here.

If we consider the quotient topology, then the answer is quite trivial: it is literally the same reasoning as before, you just replace $X$ with $U$.

On the other hand with subspace topology, the answer is only slightly harder. Normally these two don't have to coincide, but they do sometimes. A consequence of Theorem 22.1 from Munkres' "Topology" is that this happens whenever $q$ is closed and $U$ is saturated.

So first of all $q$ is closed, because given $F\subseteq X$ we have $q^{-1}(q(F))$ is either $F$ or $F\cup A$, hence closed. And thus $q(F)$ is closed.

Finally $U$ is saturated. And that's because $q^{-1}(q(U))=U\cup A=U$. Both equalities because $A\subseteq U$.

Note that it doesn't matter that $U$ is open, this holds for any $U$ as long as $A\subseteq U$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a question about it though. You said that $B\subset X\backslash A$ is open if and only if it is open in X. From what i know a subset in $X\backslash A$ is open if and only if its the intersection of an open set in X with A. Now given an open set B in $X\backslash A$, i thought we have no idea if it is open set in X, because $B'\cap A= B$ may not be open in X, as A is closed not open. The converse hold of course.

Comment: @Adronic not quite. A subset of $X\backslash A$ is open in $X\backslash A$ if it is an intersection of open subset of $X$ with $X\backslash A$. But we have a special situation here: $X\backslash A$ is open. And therefore an open subset of $X\backslash A$ is an intersection of two open subsets of $X$. And thus it is open in $X$.

Comment: Oh that was a foolish mistake. Thanks a lot!